# How to solve this error when using mice package in r?

Tags: r, statistics, missing-data, imputation, r-mice

I am trying to impute the missing values for a set of categorical and numerical variables.
The codes I am using is as follow:

```
sapply(data, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))

library(dplyr) 
data1 <- data %>%
  mutate(
    Age = as.numeric(Age),
    Sex = as.factor(Sex),
    BMI = as.numeric(BMI),
    Smoking = as.factor(Smoking),
    Alcohol = as.factor(Alcohol),
    HIV = as.factor(HIV),
    DM = as.factor(DM),
    Outcome = as.factor(Outcome),
    
      )

library(mice)
init = mice(data1, maxit=0) 
meth = init$method
predM = init$predictorMatrix

meth[c("Age", "BMI")]="norm" 
meth[c("Sex", "Smoking", "Alcohol", "HIV", "DM", "Outcome")]="logreg" 

set.seed(123)
imputed = mice(data1, method=meth, predictorMatrix=predM, m=5)

imputed1 <- complete(imputed)
```

But I keep getting this error:

iter imp variable
1   1  AgeError in solve.default(xtx + diag(pen)) :
system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 8.07738e-24

Does anyone have any solution for this?

Comment: Where does the error occur?

Comment: @dcarlson when I run this:  
imputed = mice(data1, method=meth, predictorMatrix=predM, m=5)

Comment: Does it work if you just run with default values: `imputed = mice(data1)`?